# Tikz defining a length of /tikz/cs/x[y]

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need a length long as `/tikz/cs/x[y]`.
It can be done with a trick like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\scaledx}
\newlength{\scaledy}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
x=30pt,
y=60pt,
]

\makeatletter
\pgfpointxy{1}{1}
\setlength{\scaledx}{\pgf@x};
\setlength{\scaledy}{\pgf@y};
\makeatother

\node[draw] at (0,0) { \the\scaledx };
\node[draw] at (1,1) { \the\scaledy };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

However, in the place I need my picture the `\makeatletter` breaks something. Besides this method seems a bit hackish for this task.

What is the proper way to get a length from `/tikz/cs/x[y]`?

Answer (score 3):

Can't you just define a macro in your preamble to set `\scaledx` and `\scaledy`, which needs to be surrounded by `\makeatletter....\makeatother`. Later on in your document when you need them call the macro. This way `tikzpicture` doesn't see the catcode changes.

In more detail, something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\scaledx}
\newlength{\scaledy}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\SetScales{%
  \pgfpointxy{1}{1}
  \setlength{\scaledx}{\pgf@x};
  \setlength{\scaledy}{\pgf@y};
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=30pt, y=60pt]\SetScales
    \node[draw] at (0,0) { \the\scaledx};
    \node[draw] at (1,1) { \the\scaledy };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\scaledx}
\newlength{\scaledy}
\newcommand\SetScales{%
  \pgfextractx{\scaledx}{\pgfpointxy{1}{0}}%
  \pgfextracty{\scaledy}{\pgfpointxy{0}{1}}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    x=30pt,
    y=60pt,
  ]
  \SetScales
  \node[draw] at (0,0) { \the\scaledx };
  \node[draw] at (1,1) { \the\scaledy };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\scaledx}
\newlength{\scaledy}
\newcommand\SetScales{%
  \pgfpointxy{1}{1}%
  \pgfextractx{\scaledx}{}%
  \pgfextracty{\scaledy}{}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    x=30pt,
    y=60pt,
  ]
  \SetScales
  \node[draw] at (0,0) { \the\scaledx };
  \node[draw] at (1,1) { \the\scaledy };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```